# FFmpeg: Error when copying subtitle-streams using iFFmpeg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, subtitles

*First of all: I'm new to this site and not that much experienced with FFmpeg, so I'm using the iFFmpeg GUI for Mac OS X. Also, my native language is not English.*

So here's my problem:
I got an MKV input file with several audio and subtitle streams and I want to compress it into a M4V-Container with two audio-streams and one subtitle-stream.
Encoding of the video-stream and the two audio-streams is just working fine, but when I try to add a subtitle-stream it sends me an error message: “failed opening encoder stream”.

My guess is that iFFmpeg is doing something wrong with the subtitle parameters. I tried to correct it, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

That's my input file:

> **Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR
>   16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc**
>
> **Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp,
>   1536 kb/s (default)**
>
> Stream #0:2(deu): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536
>   kb/s
>
> **Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp,
>   1536 kb/s**
>
> Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536
>   kb/s
>
> Stream #0:5(deu): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
>
> **Stream #0:6(deu): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle**
>
> Stream #0:7(deu): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
>
> Stream #0:8(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
>
> Stream #0:9(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
>
> Stream #0:10: Attachment: mjpeg

And that's what iFFmpeg generates me as a command (I know, quite long):

> ffmpeg -i Olympus\ Has\ Fallen.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:3 **-map 0:6**
>   -c:a aac -cutoff 15000 -b:a 512k -ar 48000 -c:a:1 aac -ab:2 512k -ar:2 48000 -strict experimental -async 1 -c:v libx264 -b:v 7741k -bt 655k
>   -bufsize 3096.4k -r 24 -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -trellis 1 -coder ac -subq 7 -me_range 16 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bf 3 -b_strategy 1 -refs 3 -partitions partb8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+parti8x8 -flags +loop -me_method hex -direct-pred 1 -rc_lookahead 40 -keyint_min 23 -g 240 -rc_eq 'blurcplx^(1-qcomp)' -qmin 3 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -crf 20 -level 31 -weightb 1 -8x8dct 1 -fast-pskip 1 -mixed-refs 1 -b-pyramid 1
>   -sc_threshold 40 -map_metadata 0 **-c:s mov_text** -threads 8 -y "Olympus Has Fallen.m4v"

I would be very pleased if anyone could help me 'cause I tried for so long and it's just frustrating that it isn't working.

Comment: `m4v` or `mp4` will not support subtitle as stream when you use `ffmpeg`. The only way to do that with an mp4 container in ffmpeg would be to "burn" it.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause Apple is also using M4V-Containers for iTunes downloads and I think some movies on iTunes got subtitles...

Comment: Well Wikipedia says, MP4-Container can hold "MPEG-4 Timed Text" subtitles

Comment: @Rajib I believe MP4 can use what `ffmpeg` calls `mov_text` for softsubs, but I've never tried it.

Comment: I was successful with `Handbrake` not with `ffmpeg` to put subtitles in `mp4`, but I admit it was a while back- have not tried with the newest `ffmeg`.